# Select or move dynamic Buttons using arrow key in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have panel. dynamically i have created more than 10 buttons. the panel contains that all buttons. i want to select the any buttons using arrow up/Down/Left/Right?
please give some idea's.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CWot.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can hookup the `KeyDown Event` of the button like this:

```
Public Sub DesignPane_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
  If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
    txtBox.Location.Y += 1
  ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
    txtBox.Location.X += 1
  ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
    txtBox.Location.Y -= 1
  ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then
    txtBox.Location.X -= 1
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. its did not fire the arrow key event.

Comment: how did u hook up the `KeyDown` event?  You need add something like this while creating button dynamically `Button1.KeyDown = AddressOf DesignPane_KeyDown`

Comment: This is my code. ___  For Jcount = 0 To DvAllTableM.Count - 1
 BtnName = New Button
 BtnName .Height = 100
 BtnName.Width = 100
 BtnName .Name = DvAllTableM(Jcount)("TableName")
 BtnName.Tag = DvAllTableM(Jcount)("UID")
 BtnName .Text =  DvAllTableM(Jcount)("TableName")
TableBasePanel.Controls.Add(BtnName)
Next
 AddHandler BtnName.KeyDown, AddressOf ButtonDown

Comment: `For Jcount = 0 To DvAllTableM.Count - 1 
BtnName = New Button 
BtnName .Height = 100 
BtnName.Width = 100 
BtnName .Name = DvAllTableM(Jcount)("TableName") 
BtnName.Tag = DvAllTableM(Jcount)("UID") 
BtnName .Text = DvAllTableM(Jcount)("TableName") 
TableBasePanel.Controls.Add(BtnName) 
AddHandler BtnName.KeyDown, AddressOf ButtonDown
Next`

Comment: I tried bro. but result is same. 'ButtonDown' function called when i click right arrow but its not going inside if condition

Comment: This is correct format? Private Sub ButtonDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
        Try
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
                BtnName.Y += 1
            ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Right AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control Then
                BtnName.X += 1
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

Comment: Hi Bro, I did with FlowlayoutPanel Instead of Panel Control. Now its working fine except one synorio. I can select the buttons from left to right and right to left. but i also need up down functionalities, please help me.

Comment: When use your code its saying  'X' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'.

Comment: i think it should be `Location.X`

Comment: I Tried Buttonname.Location.X += 1 . Its said  Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment.